# Answer difference of same series with different index

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, geometric-series

Consider these two series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}3\left(\frac {1}{2}\right)^n=3$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}3\left(\frac {1}{2}\right)^n=6$$

Everybody knows that there should be a difference,
What I know is, if $\left | r \right | < 1$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}ar^{n-1}=\frac {a}{1-r}$$ 
I also can change the index $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}ar^{n}=\frac {a}{1-r}$$
I want you to dissect first two examples.
The question is, 
Why the answer of the first two series are different?

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly are you asking for?

Comment: Why the answer of the first two series are different?

Comment: The first example has $a=3/2$ and $r=1/2$ the second has $a=3,r=1/2$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Can you tell me exactly how I can fast recognize the difference between two? because they seem to be the same.

Comment: @FreeMind Write out the first few terms of each series to train your intuition.

Comment: $a$ is always the first term of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty ar^{n-1}$. In the above, the first term of the first series is $3/2$, the first term of the second series is $3$.

Comment: because of the index since it starts with zero while other starts with 1 ... on second series you get extra $3$

Comment: In case this alternative way of looking at it helps, the exponent in the first sum is $n$. In order to use your first formula, you need the exponent to be $n-1$.

Answer (score 1):

Why $e_1:=(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}3(\frac {1}{2})^n) \neq e_2:=(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}3(\frac {1}{2})^n)$?
Because $e_1 = e_2 - 3(\frac{1}{2})^0 = e_2 - 3$.
And read the comments above, which are more useful than my answer.